# Where to create my objects? Multiple views in project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop

I have a project that will have a lot of views (20 in total). They are displayed in sequence and the user makes certain decisions before tapping a button to make the next view appear. When all 20 views have been displayed, it goes back to the first view.

I also need to create a lot of instances of 3 different objects. So there may be 40 different instances of object1, 20 of object2, and 30 of object3. Each view needs to know about all of these instances and will often change instance variables.

I need to pass these instances between the views. I think I will do this by passing a pointer along to the next view. My question (I've finally got there), is where to create all these instances in the first place? In the original View Controller? Or in the AppDelegate?

Many thanks for any pointers (pun intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think MVC

When designing the model, consider diferent aproaches: CoreData, serialization in filesystem, in memory using singletone...

And remember: load lazily

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd use CoreData for this. You start creating objects in initial view controller. Then after user manipulates the object you pass that object into next view controller (probably via `UINavigationController`) and create appropriate objects there as needed and so on and so forth.

On a side note - please rethink your navigation flow and user experience. User might be tired enough after as little as 5th configuration view.